# Why does my Twitter stream give me the HTTP Error: 406?

Tags: python, tweepy

That's my code. Every thing works well, but when the Twitter Stream should start there comes the following error: `Stream encountered HTTP Error: 406`
With the normal stream it works well, but with the asynchronous stream it doesn't. Where is my mistake?

```
import discord 
import tweepy 
import tweepy.asynchronous

class Stream(tweepy.asynchronous.AsyncStream):
    async def on_connect(self):
        print("connected")

    async def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

    async def on_exception(self, exception):
        print(exception)
        print("!exception")

        """async def on_request_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)"""
        #If An error occurs then the programm should be restartet 
        """await restart(discord_client=client, twitter_stream = self)"""

    async def on_closed(self, resp):
        print(resp)

class Client(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        #creating stream
        stream = Stream(keys + tokens)
        #creating api
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys)
        auth.set_access_token(tokens)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        #getting specific users which the stream should follow
        follow_list = [screen_name]
        follower_ids = []
        for _ in follow_list:
            follow = int(api.get_user(screen_name = _).id)
            print(follow)
            follower_ids.append(follow)
        print(str(follower_ids))
        #starting Stream
        stream.filter(follow = follow_list)
        print("start")

client = Client()
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you're passing invalid IDs for [`AsyncStream.filter`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asyncstream.html#tweepy.asynchronous.AsyncStream.filter)'s `follow` parameter.

`follow_list` seems to be a list with a single screen name or a list of screen names, not a list of user IDs. It seems like you might have intended to use `follower_ids` instead.

A 406 Not Acceptable HTTP Error means:

> At least one request parameter is invalid. For example, the filter endpoint returns this status if:
>
> - The track keyword is too long or too short.
> - An invalid bounding box is specified.
> - Neither the track nor follow parameter are specified.
> - The follow user ID is not valid.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting